# How we can get the updated data by refreshing the cache using the cache_page in DRF with the same route?

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, cache-control

**The website is similar in functionality to Twitter** and we're using a Django caching mechanism for the feed but when the user created his post he is not able to find his post for the next 10 minutes due to the caching and we want to show the latest results to the user so, how we can show the latest data to the user after creating his post using the same route

Here is the urls.py code

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from . import views
CACHE_TIME=60*10
urlpatterns = [
    path('', cache_page(CACHE_TIME)(views.PostListAPIView.as_view()), name="post-list")
]
```

if we call the API --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/posts/ then data will be stored in the cache for the next 10 minutes but I want to refresh after the specific event so, how can we get the updated data before the 10 minutes

also,
We have found a solution for it if we pass [http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/posts/?{username}=true](http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/posts/?%7Busername%7D=true) then we can get the latest data for the user **but is there any other better approach or possibility to show the latest data? if yes, then please list the method and some details about it**

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases you will need to delete the old cache. You will get them soon.
Regarding your issue, I assume that you just need to cover a case: invalidate cache after a post is added.

This is best approach for you:

1. Using signal to detect when a post is added
2. From django cache docs, it says that cache.delete('key') should be enough. So just need to use it, and call a function to warm-up the cache if needed then.

Sample code

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def invalidate_post_list_cache(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    This signal helps invalidate post list cache and warm-up cache
    """
    cache.delete('key')
    call_function_to_warm_up_cache()
```

There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things – Phil Karlton

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm using cache_page on the entire route in the urls.py file because the DRF generic method does not accept it on the class-based method. so., how can we delete the entire route/API cache? and cache it again?

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAbbas You just need delete the cache by route and warm up the cache again. Sample code:

```
from django.core.cache import cache


# ...
cache.delete('my_view')```